# Are hitting times of Brownian motion independent?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Suppose that $B_t$ is a standard Brownian motion. And $T_a$, $T_b$ are the hitting time whereas $a<0$, $b>0$. Then are these two random variables independent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, hitting times for the same Brownian Motion are not independent.  Think of it this way: given $T_a = s$, $B_s = a$ so if $a \ne b$, $B_t$ is much less likely to be close to $b$ when $t$ is near $s$, and therefore $T_b$ is much less likely to be close to $s$.

Comment: I see. Thanks very much!

Comment: May I know what's the probability of T_b < T_a

Comment: if $c=\mathbb{P}(T_b<T_a)$, then, by OST, $0=\mathbb{E}[B_{T_a\wedge T_b}]=a(1-c)+bc$. Solve for $c$.